# Dompdf package for Laravel 4 return 500 when many ( >9 ) pages are generated

Tags: php, laravel, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm using this [Dompdf package for Laravel 4](https://github.com/thujohn/pdf-l4)  by Jonathan Thuau 
and I'm getting server error whenever I try to generate more than 9 gapes otherwise it works.

Below is the screenshot of the error 
[image]

Below is also my config file , let me know if I have to change anything in that

```
return array(
'DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
'DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED' => true,
'DOMPDF_PDF_BACKEND' => 'CPDF',
'DOMPDF_DEFAULT_MEDIA_TYPE' => 'screen',
'DOMPDF_DEFAULT_PAPER_SIZE' => 'letter',
'DOMPDF_DEFAULT_FONT' => 'serif',
'DOMPDF_DPI' => 96,
'DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP' => false,
'DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE' => false,
'DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT' => false,
'DOMPDF_ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT' => true,
'DEBUGPNG' => false,
'DEBUGKEEPTEMP' => false,
'DEBUGCSS' => false,
'DEBUG_LAYOUT' => false,
'DEBUG_LAYOUT_LINES' => true,
'DEBUG_LAYOUT_BLOCKS' => true,
'DEBUG_LAYOUT_INLINE' => true,
'DOMPDF_FONT_HEIGHT_RATIO' => 1.1,
'DEBUG_LAYOUT_PADDINGBOX' => true,
'DOMPDF_ENABLE_HTML5PARSER' => false,
'DOMPDF_ENABLE_FONTSUBSETTING' => false,
'DOMPDF_ADMIN_USERNAME' => 'user',
'DOMPDF_ADMIN_PASSWORD' => 'password',
);
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your HTML? And what about the actual error causing the 500 (it's probably a php error and you should be able to get something more specific). You might just be experiencing resource exhaustion if you don't have much memory allocated for PHP processes.

Comment: @BrianS thanks for pointing out resource exhaustion , I just solve with giving more increasing memory and max execution time  and posted the code answer , Thank you again , I appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to resource exhaustion and I have to add to following lines on top of the page and it worked

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Comment: These settings will work in a pinch, but they're a little extreme. You could exhaust available memory for your entire system or, depending on your configuration, the script could run indefinitely blocking other requests.

Comment: thanks @BrianS , what do you think are best practices for solving this issue ?

Comment: I would start by incrementing memory limit and execution time incrementally to try and find the sweet spot. Keeping the memory limit below your available RAM is a good idea. It will take some trial-and-error.

Comment: If you don't need to give the PDF to the end user immediately you can generate the PDFs out of band and notify the end user when the PDF is available. In that way you can serialize generation so that you're not quickly using up available memory by trying to generate more than one PDF at a time.

Comment: Also, make sure you're using the latest release. We're trying to improve resource utilization.